# Register Module with PHP validation

Tags: php

I have a registration module with PHP validation.

This coding shows the error and how to check the username availability using MySQL.
I gave HTML file PHP validation File.

This is my runtime error:
`syntax error, unexpected $end in F:\xampp\htdocs\mycode\exec.php on line 60`

Thanks in advance.

**`exec.php`**

```
$todo = $_POST['todo'];
if ($todo == "submit-form")
{
    $status_form = "OK";
    $msg = "";

    $uname = $_POST['uname'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $pass1 = $_POST['cpass'];
    $sex = $_POST['gender'];
    $dob = $_POST['dob'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $mob = $_POST['mob'];

    if ($uname = '' || $name = '' || $email = '' || $pass = '' || $pass1 = '' || $sex = '' || $dob = '' || $city = '' || $mob = '')
    {
        $status_form = "NOTOK";
        $msg .= "fields r empty<br>";
    }
    if (strlen($uname) < 5)
    {
        $status_form = "NOTOK";
        $msg .= "Your Name must be more than 5 char  length<br>";
    }
    if (isset($todo) and $todo == "submit-form")
    {
        if (!eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email))
        {
            $status_form = "NOTOK";
            $msg .= "invalid Email<br>";
        }
        if (strcmp($pass, $pass1) != 0)
        {
            $status_form = "NOTOK";
            $msg .= "password do not match<br>";
        }
        if (strlen($sex) < 1)
        {
            $status_form = "NOTOK";
            $msg .= "Please select Sex<br>";
        }
        if (is_numeric($mob))
        {
            $status_form = "NOTOK";
            $msg .= "Please enter numeric<br>";
        }
        if ($status_form == "OK")
        {
            // do your data insertion as validation is passed
            $msg = "Thanks <br> Your data validation is passed ";
            header("Location: thank.php?msg=$msg");
        }
        else
        {

            while (list ($key, $val) = each($_POST))
            //echo $pd;
                header("Location: reg2.php?msg=$msg&$pd");
        }// end of else if status_form is not ok
    }// checking of todo value
} // was missing
```

**`reg2.php`**

```
<div <?php $msg = $_GET['msg'];
    echo "<font color=red>$msg</font>"; ?> </div>
<form method="post" action="exec.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="todo" value="submit-form" />
    <table width="475" height="167" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td height="23">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="159" height="23">Username</td>
            <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="170">
                <input type="text" name="uname" value="<?php echo '$uname'; ?>" />       </td>
            <td width="118">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="23">Name</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo '$name'; ?>" /></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="23">Email</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo '$email'; ?>"/></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="pass" value="<?php echo '$pass'; ?>" /></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>confirm password </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="cpass" value="<?php echo '$cpass'; ?>" /></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gender</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />Male<input type="radio"  name="gender" value="female" />Female</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date of Birth </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="dob" value="<?php echo '$dob'; ?>"/></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>City</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo '$city'; ?>"/></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mobile No </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input name="mob" type="text" maxlength="10" value="<?php echo '$mob'; ?>"/></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Profile Photo </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="file" name="file" /></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: NetBeans 7.0.1, `Alt` + `Shift` + `F` -- You'll note the `was missing` final brace. If you're using Notepad, use something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a parser error.  It is generally caused by a mismatched parenthesis or curly bracket.

You evaluate $todo twice but only close it once.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have more `{` than `}` in your code. **Use a real IDE** such as [Eclipse PDT](http://eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/), [Aptana](http://aptana.com/), etc. should tell you directly where the missing `}` is.

But even with simpler environments such as [Geany](http://www.geany.org/) or [Context](http://www.contexteditor.org/), if you **properly [indent your code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style)**, you should be able to see clearly where the missing `}` is (are ?).

BTW, another obvious critical problem is that you confuse **==** and **=**, in the "big test" `if($uname='' || $name='' || etc.)`.

Spend some minutes on **reading some PHP Best practice tutorials**, such as [this one](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/30-php-best-practices-for-beginners/) or [this one](http://www.phpvs.net/2008/06/04/ten-php-best-practices-tips-that-will-get-you-a-job/), easily found by Googling for *"php best practices"*.